# Where is the wine?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

In Realm of the Mad God, in the Wine Cellar, Somehow you get wine that regenerates HP or MP. I was wondering if you get it from the barrels, Oryx's minions, or even Oryx himself.

Answer (score 1):

The wine bottles are soulbound drops from Oryx's minions. I've never seen one drop from Oryx, and the barrels are empty.

Edit: you don't have to be in the wine cellar to get wine bottle drops. I've gotten them in bags from Brutes of Oryx in the main castle as well.